# How to get jquery.Datatable's data to respect angular 2-way binding

Tags: angularjs, datatable, datatables

I have a json object that may be modified by local conditions (not async ajax calls). I want this json object to be output on a [datatables](https://datatables.net/index) grid.

I have the table displaying the data just fine, however if the data changes, the grid does not. Do I have to call the constructor datatables every time? I would prefer to just use 2-way binding, but I am not sure. I have gotten it to update using a $watch, but I'd like to avoid using a $watch on this large object if I can. It could have 1000's of rows.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3S7WX/2/) showing the datatable load, and the data it runs on changing after 3000 millis (simple $timeout). Is there a way to get the table to detect the change in the json object and refresh itself? Or do I need to do something different in the Angular code?

I am using a directive to load the table:

```
.directive('myTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        options: '=',
        columns: '='
    },
    template:
        '<table id="balancesTable"></table>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {        
        scope.options["aaData"] = scope.data;
        scope.options["aoColumnDefs"] = scope.columns;
        elem.dataTable(scope.options);
    }
  };
})
```

My Controller (edited for brevity... see fiddle for full code):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $("#data-preview").css("color","green");
    $scope.dataObj = [ { "balanceType": "Available Funds", ... } ];

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.dataObj = [ { "balanceType": "Available Funds", ... different data ...} ];
      $("#data-preview").css("color","red");
    },
    3000);

    // columns settings for data table
    $scope.columnDefs = [
      {
       "mData": "balanceType",
       "sTitle": "Balance Type",
       "aTargets":[0],
       "sWidth": "200px"
      },
      {
         ...
      }
    ];

    // data table settings for table to not show search, pagination and allow column resize
    $scope.overrideOptions = {
      "bSort": true,
      "bPaginate": false,
      "sDom": "Rlfrtip",
      "bFilter": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bInfo": false
    };
  })
```

HTML:

```
<pre id="data-preview">{{dataObj}} | json}}</pre>
<my-table options="overrideOptions" data="dataObj" columns="columnDefs"><my-table>
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: @NathanBiles We ended up moving to [http://ui-grid.info/](uiGrid), so I never had to. Though, off the top of my head I might try to get around this issue by putting a watch on the collection I want shown in the grid, and use datatable's API to update itself, or re-call its constructor. This is the kinda of situation where I feel you might need to employ an $apply() to get angular to work with a 3rd party library.